# Comparing 2 RPT reports via command line

Tags: compare, report, filenotfoundexception, rpt, cmdline-args

I want to compare 2 RPT reports via command line. I am trying to use -compare option, but it is giving me FileNotFoundException. Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this.

Comment: On Linux, diff file1 file2

Comment: can you please provide me the entire command?

Comment: can you please provide me the entire command? I am using below command for comparing 2 rpt reports, in linux.                                                                                        ./cmdline.sh -workspace /project/rpt_work/RPT_Workspace -project RPTWorkloads -schedule Schedules/Simple_Schedule.testsuite -eclipsehome /project/rpt_im/RPT -plugins /project/rpt_im/IMShared/plugins -exportlog /newRunTestSchedule.log -results RPTWorkloads /results -exportstatshtml /project/rpt_report -compare "/Report1.stats.html,/Report2.stats.html"  -vmargs -Xmx2G

Comment: Just `diff file1 file2` where file1 and file2 are the names of the files you are comparing. If the files are identical, you get no output, otherwise you get the differences output on the screen.